# Hooking up a laptop to an HDTV via VGA

Tags: windows, laptop, hdmi, vga, hdtv

I have a 2-3 year old laptop running XBMC, and I have an HDTV that I'd like to connect it to.

The only output that the laptop has is VGA (and S-Video - I don't know if the TV supports it) .

The TV doesn't support VGA input, but takes HDMI.

--

Is it worth buying a VGA-to-HDMI converter? As in this:

[image]

--

Are there any other, cheaper options available?
There's a lot of information around the WWW, but a lot of it's outdated and it's hard to digest everything.

I know of at least one other option, and that's a **USB to HDMI connection**, but I don't even know what to look for or where to get started on that one. I also suspect it might be a little more complicated. If it's cheaper then it could be worth it.

**EDIT**
More Details:

- Intel integrated graphics card (Intel 945 Express Chipset Family)
- The TV supports up to 1080p resolution

Comment: Post more details please: which graphics card? and what's the resolution of the TV?

Comment: @Molly - I've added the requested details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine - the Intel 945 Express does support 1080p output as a resolution **however** I doubt that you will be able to play any high definition videos as it really will struggle at that resolution.

Comment: Can I simply output the 1280x800 resolution that my laptop uses? 720p videos play just fine on that resolution

Comment: Yes you can then, however for best results, you may want to check to see if your TV has a PC mode or the ability to not stretch the image and/or put a black border around it - otherwise it will look stretched and warped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  For the best experience you'll need to convert the VGA or USB to HDMI.
You could use s-video but the resolution will be limited to standard def TV quality.